# How do I exclude Quarkus Graphql-UI from JWT authentication?

Tags: graphql, jwt, quarkus, smallrye

I´m using Microprofile-GraphQL extension (https://quarkus.io/guides/microprofile-graphql) for Quarkus together with Smallrye JWT (https://quarkus.io/guides/security-jwt) to secure my GraphQL endpoint.

This however blocks the Graphql UI that comes with the Microprofile extension under **/graphql-ui**

**Is there any way to permitt / allow routes that are not defined in your own rest controllers?**

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
quarkus.http.auth.permission.permit.paths=/graphql-ui/*
quarkus.http.auth.permission.permit.policy=permit
```

should do it, please see [Quarkus Authorization](https://quarkus.io/guides/security-authorization)